# React js stop looping background video

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make a page with looping background video with `React js`.

When I compile the code I can see the video is playing straight away on the browser but when I click the link of website, the video is not playing. I should click the `Home` button in the page and starts again.

I used

```
<video src={BackVideo} autoplay="true" loop="true">
```

I could not use :

`react-native-video`

library because I got an error when I import the library in the code.

Also I have one more problem that the video is not playing in `Safari` at all.

Can someone help me please.

Here is my part of `Javascript` file

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="bgded overlay">
        {/* Menu, call the menu component with the ChangeViewButtonClick function recieved from Dashbaord */}
          <Menu ChangeViewButtonClick={this.props.ChangeViewButtonClick} />

        </div>

        <header className="v-header container">

      <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">

        <video src={BackVideo} autoplay="true" loop="true"> </video>

    </div>
    <div className="header-overlay"></div>
    <div className="header-content">

       <article>
              <h1 className="heading">Something</h1>
              <h2 className="heading">something too</h2>



            </article>

    </div>
       </header>

        {/* Start of Overview */}
        <div className="wrapper row3">
          <main className="hoc container clear">
            <article className="two_third first">
              <h4 className="font-x2 font-x3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                Exercitationem, nihil.
              </h4>


            </article>

          </main>
        </div>
        {/* End of Overview */}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure out and might someone have the same problem.

use **autoPlay loop muted** so;

```
<video className='VideoTag' autoPlay loop muted>
      <source src={BackVideo} type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```